# Deleted Bootcamp partition and it just disappeared. Nothing to merge with OSX partition

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I had Windows 10 Bootcamp on my MacBook Pro 15" 2015. I just tried to remove the Bootcamp with Bootcamp assistant by clicking "restore" and it gave me an error saying "The disk cannot be partitioned or restored to a single partition."

So I followed instructions given by [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/142873/162991) and I deleted the Bootcamp partition using Disk Utility.

The partition was successfully deleted and there was 200GB of unused space. I tried to merge it with my OSX partition and it gave me an error. Forgot what type of error exactly, something about one of partitions being broken (wrong amount of blocks or something?)

Now the problem is that the 200GB of unused space (previously used by Bootcamp) just disappeared. Nowhere to be seen.

[image]

What can I do to fix this? How can I get my OSX partition back to the original 500GB?

**diskutil list**

[image]

**diskutil cs list**

> No CoreStorage logical volume groups found

**sudo fdisk /dev/disk0**

[image]

**sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0**

[image]

Comment: If you can edit your question and post the output from the following Terminal application commands, I will try to simulate your conditions. If successful, I will post a solution. `diskutil  list`, `diskutil  cs  list`, `sudo  fdisk  /dev/disk0` and `sudo  gpt  -r  show  /dev/disk0`. These commands will not change your computer. Some may ask for your login password. This is normal.

Comment: Maybe try the Disk Utillity in the Recovery HD. (cmd + r)

Comment: @DavidAnderson I edited my question and added the commands. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You show in your posted image that the partition is encrypted. I was unaware a partition could be encrypted without using core storage. Anyway, I believe the correct command to fix your drive is given below.

```
sudo  diskutil  resizevolume  /dev/disk0s2  R
```

The command should move `/dev/disk0s3` to the bottom of `disk0` while resizing `/dev/disk0s2` to maximum size. I am not sure if the `sudo` prefix is required.